# How to convert Object to String in mule esb?

Tags: mule, dropbox-api

I am working with Mule ESB and our goal is to use dropbox as a end point connector means to store data to dropbox(from CSV/doc or any other data source). We are able to store data to drop box but data stored in the form of object and that is not in readable format so how to convert object to string so that it can be in readable format ?

Answer (score 1):

Mule already has Object to String transformer to transform String from Object :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Transformers

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're after is called object serialization, and you have many choices about how to do it in a way that people can read it.

Perhaps the oldest way in java (which is the language Mule is based on) is to implement a [toString()](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) method and format your object's data as you like.  Of course, this means your message payload must be an instance of a class you can make changes to.  If you choose this method, you can simply add an `<object-to-string-transformer />` as Anirban suggested.

Some common ways people do this, especially with Mule ESB, is to use [XML](http://www.w3.org/XML/) or [JSON](http://json.org/) to represent the information in the object.  Mule includes strong support of [XML](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XML+Module+Reference) and [JSON](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/JSON+Module+Reference).  Many times, you can simply add a `<json:object-to-json-transformer />` to your flow, and the payload will be converted automatically.  For this to work, your payload needs to be simple types such as Maps and Lists, or an instance of a class with JAXB mappings.

Comment: what about a flowvar, how to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing .
 if you are asking about the transformation in mule  add this in your  XML file `<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>` after the dropbox component.